# DIV floating and sizing problem

Tags: css, html, sizing

I have div sizing and floating problem. when I have tiny text it is OK:
[SEE IMAGE](http://s2.postimage.org/4qw170zc1/Screenshot_1.png)
but look what happens when I have big text
[SEE IMAGE](http://s2.postimage.org/4qw2ukbtt/Screenshot_2.png)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="news">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="url">
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="title">TITLE</div>
        <div class="text">TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.news{
    float:left;
    padding:5px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.news > .img{
    float:left;
    width:75px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.news > .img > img{
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
}
.news > .wrap{
    float:left;
}
.news > .wrap > .title{
    font-size:14px;
}
.news > .wrap > .text{
    text-align:justify;
}
```

please help..

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should be helpful:

http://www.monkeydoit.com/wrap-text-images-css.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to set width to your `.wrap` container.

Comment: .wrap must be dinamic in diwth

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
.news {
    float:left;
    padding:5px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin-bottom:10px
}
.news .img {
    float:left;
    width:75px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.news .wrap .title { font-size:14px; }
.news .wrap .text { text-align:justify; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the correct width wrap div

or

Give the 100% width on news div